# Requests works and URLFetch doesn't

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, urlfetch

I'm trying to make a request to the particle servers in python in a google app engine app.

In my terminal, I can complete the request simply and successfully with requests as:

```
res = requests.get('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices', params={"access_token": {ACCESS_TOKEN}})
```

But in my app, the same thing doesn't work with urlfetch, which keeps telling me it can't find the access token:

```
    url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices'
    payload = {"access_token": {ACCESS_TOKEN}}
    form_data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
    res = urlfetch.fetch(
        url=url,
        payload=form_data,
        method=urlfetch.GET,
        headers={
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        follow_redirects=False 
    )
```

I have no idea what the problem is, and no way to debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a nutshell, your problem is that in your `urlfetch` sample you're embedding your access token into the request body, and since you're issuing a GET request -which cannot carry any request body with them- this information gets discarded.

**Why does your first snippet work?**

Because `requests.get()` takes that optional `params` argument that means: "take this dictionary I give you, convert all its key/value pairs into a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and append it to the main URL"

So, behind the curtains, `requests.get()` is building a string like this:

`https://api.particle.io/v1/devices?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

That's the correct endpoint you should point your GET requests to.

**Why doesn't your second snippet work?**

This time, `urlfetch.fetch()` uses a different syntax than `requests.get()` (but equivalent nonetheless). The important bit to note here is that `payload` argument **doesn't** mean the same as our `params` argument that you used before in `requests.get()`.

`urlfetch.fetch()` expects our query string -if any- to be already urlencoded into the URL (that's why `urllib.urlencode()` comes into play here). On the other hand, `payload` is where you should put your request body in case you were issuing a POST, PUT or PATCH request, but particle.io's endpoint is not expecting your OAuth access token to be there.

Something like this should work (disclaimer: not tested):

```python
auth = {"access_token": {ACCESS_TOKEN}}
url_params = urllib.urlencode(auth)
url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices?%s' % url_params

res = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    method=urlfetch.GET,
    follow_redirects=False 
)
```

Notice how now we don't need your previous `Content-type` header anymore, since we aren't carrying any content after all. Hence, `headers` parameter can be removed from this example call.

For further reference, take a look at `urlfetch.fetch()` [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) that will hopefully give you a better insight into HTTP methods, parameters and request bodies than my poor explanation here.

**PS:** If particle.io servers support it (they should), you should move away from this authentication schema and carry your tokens in a `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` header instead. Carrying access tokens in URLs is not a good idea because they are much more visible that way and tend to stay logged in servers, hence posing a security risk. On the other hand, in a TLS session all request headers are always encrypted so your auth tokens are well hidden there.

Comment: yup, this is it; with better detail than my answer below. THANKS!!

Comment: I see; I was securing it so it wasn't plain text in the server, but I wasn't thinking about the url send itself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, as it turns out, one cannot include a payload for a GET request using Urlfetch. Instead, one has to include the parameters in the url using the '?' syntax as follows:

```
url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices'
url = url + '?access_token=' + {ACCESS_TOKEN}
res = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    method=urlfetch.GET,
    follow_redirects=False 
)
```

this worked for me.